# Gatling stress testing for socket.io

Tags: scala, socket.io, gatling

I'm trying to test socket.io with gatling and i'm using exec block:

```
//...
 .exec(session => {
 val socket = IO.socket(socketURL + session.get("token").as[String])
 val printListener: Emitter.Listener = new Emitter.Listener {
    override def call(args: AnyRef*): Unit = {
       println(args) //Stop time here for example
    }
 }
 socket.on("info", printListener)
 socket.connect()
 socket.emit("info", "{}") //Start timer
 session
 })
//...
```

Is any way to have time of execution of exec block in gatling report?

Answer (score 1):

I know almost zero about Gatling I read that `Session` is a kind of `Map` so you might do something like this `sessiont.set("startTime", currentTimeMillis)` but it would return another session, bc it is immutable so you would need to do a little more. 
If not you might do a workaround something like this:

```
//...
 .exec(session => {
 var start:Long = 0L
 val socket = IO.socket(socketURL + session.get("token").as[String])
 val printListener: Emitter.Listener = new Emitter.Listener {
    override def call(args: AnyRef*): Unit = {
       println( "Time: "+((System.nanoTime - start) / 1000000) )
       println(args) //Stop time here for example
    }
 }
 socket.on("info", printListener)
 socket.connect()
 socket.emit("info", (()=>{ start = System.nanoTime;"{}"})()) //Start timer
 session
 })
//...
```

I didn't test this code.. it is almost a psudo code, it is a bit ugly but I consider it could work. 
I hope this helps.
Cheers.

**EDITED!**